# Facebook pixel not tracking hashbang URL

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I am working on an Angular SPA that uses state routing for navigation. I have the Facebook pixel installed and working correctly (verified with Facebook Pixel Helper). However, if the URL is something like http://example.com/#/about-us then Facebook records http://example.com and drops the rest of the URL.

Has anyone figured out how to get Facebook to track the entire URL?

Comment: Have you tried to disable hashbang mode and activate htm5 mode?

Comment: I am hosting out of an S3 bucket so from what I have read I cannot turn off hashbangs.  If anyone has a resource that says otherwise, while not breaking SEO, then I'd be more than happy to do that.